# Has Twitter removed the unauthenticated user RSS timeline feeds?

Tags: twitter

I have previously used the following URL to access my tweets and embed them on a website:

`http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/my_username.rss`

It seems that just this morning though, I'm getting the following error:

`Sorry, that page does not exist`

Does anyone know what might have happened to this service, and what an alternative might be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=USERNAME

Comment: Worked with https.  [link](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline)

Comment: Great, this works perfectly. Its a shame that Twitter's documentation isn't a little easier to find your way around as I was trawling through it this morning for something like this!

Comment: Please be aware that this will this method of accessing feeds has been deprecated by Twitter and will be removed during March 2013.

Instead twitter are moving to requiring OAUTH access. See here for more information: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/10803

Answer (score 4):

It appears that this is a permanent change made by Twitter ([see Twitter API's tweet](https://twitter.com/twitterapi/status/256127405553496066))

Instead they're moving to a versioning system like below:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=twitter_username
```

By changing the user_timeline file extention you're able to receive the feed in different formats, IE:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=twitter_username
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitter_username
```

Comment: Thanks for the background! It's a shame that Twitter didn't 301-redirect the old feed URLs.